# Why eyedropper is not working in invoke popup while it is working on Panel?

Tags: python

I have a `PointerProperty` that selects objects I want to add a shortcut to the operator but the eyedropper is not working in this operator as it is working in the panel.

I want the eyedropper to work as it does on the panel.

````
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(CUSTOM_PT_OPERATOR.bl_idname)
        
        
class CUSTOM_PT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operator"
    bl_idname = "custom.does_nothing"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    
    def execute(self,context):
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self)
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(context.scene,"select_obj")
        
    
classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_PT_OPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.select_obj = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Don't know what you mean. Your exact same code works for me. Try executing `bpy.ops.custom.does_nothing('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` when calling from python api.